# Get a mask format from a flutter API

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my application I have an API that returns a mask, it can be CEP, CNPJ, CPF, whatever, the user that will choose.
What I want is to see how I can put a mask to fit the mask placed in the API.

This is how my API data comes:

```
  {
        "id": 26934,
        "label": "Campo de Texto - Com Máscara",
        "required": true,
        "type": "T",
        "mascara": "99999-999",
        "formatacao": "S",
        "format": "S",
        "originalFormat": "S",
        "html5Input": false,
        "codcampodinamico": 26934,
        "fieldSize": "M",
        "value": null,
        "values": []
    },
```

here is my code:

[image]

but when I do it this way, when I go to type in my field, it doesn't let me type anything, I click on the key and it just adds the 99999-999

[image]

Comment: Wellcome to the StackOverflow.

Comment: Which library/package are you using for MaskedTextController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon, I managed to solve it, as my API returned 9999 .. it did not understand the nines as a mask so I did this:

```
mask: form.mask,
      
filter: {"9": RegExp('')}
        
type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add onChangedMethod on **CompoUserSneha** *widget*.

```
 onChanged: (value) {
     maskedController.text=value;
    },
```

This may allow to change the value of 99999-999.